# HAProxy config for sub-domains

Tags: haproxy

I need an example HAProxy config to do the following:

Server1 = 192.168.0.177 ( I did not give the servers names - only IP's)

On Server1, I run HAproxy as well as Apache.

Apache on Server1 is setup to listen on port 8080 now, and has two Virtual Hosts correctly setup for two sub-domains - each serving its own website content.
Sub-domain 1 = s.mydomain.com
Sub-domain 2 = x.mydomain.com

I have a second server running on 192.168.0.233.

I want to setup HAProxy to listen to s.mydomain.com and then forward it to Apache on the same server ( 192.168.0.177), x.mydomain.com and forward it to Apache on the same server (192.168.0.177) and y.mydomain.com and forward traffic to the second server (192.168.0.233).

I do not need any load balancing at this point, just routing/forwarding as described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go,

```
global
  #debug

defaults
  mode http
  option httpclose
  timeout connect 5000ms
  timeout client 50000ms
  timeout server 50000ms

backend same_server
  server same_server 127.0.0.1:8001

backend second_server
  server second_server 192.168.0.233:80

frontend app *:80
  acl sub_y hdr(host) -i y.mydomain.com
  use_backend second_server if sub_y
  default_backend same_server
```

Comment: Thank you. This is giving me *some* results, but the redirection/routing to the second server is not working - it looks like it is going into a loop and eventually ends up at the backup/default backend server. I also had to use the actual 192.168.0.177 IP for the "same_server" before it started to work for the other two domains hosted on the same server. Any ideas what could be causing this, or how I can troubleshoot?

Comment: @Monty check the HAProxy logs and those in the web servers.  Compare.

Comment: This is an extract from haproxy logs

[/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:43] : 'frontend' cannot handle unexpected argument '*:80'.

Here is the bottom of my haproxy.cfg

backend same_server
  server same_server 192.168.0.177:8080

backend second_server
  server second_server 192.168.0.223

frontend app *:80
  acl sub_y hdr(host) -i y.mydomain.com
  acl sub_x hdr(host) -i x.mydomain.com
  acl sub_z hdr(host) -i z.mydomain.com
  use_backend second_server if sub_y
  use_backend same_server if sub_x
  use_backend same_server if sub_z
  default_backend same_server

Comment: OK, Found the issue from logs

1. frontend statement was wrong - should be:

frontend same_server
bind *:80